# redirect any subdomain to a folder of the same subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to create a conditional redirect and rewrite for apache that accomplishes the following

1. redirect any subdomain to a folder of the same subdomain ie

   - subdomain.domain.com redirects to subdomain.domain.com/store
   - subdomain2.domain.com redirect to subdomain2.domain.com/store
2. all subdomains with www. would do the same thing except remove the www ie

   - www.subdomain.domain.com redirects to subdomain.domain.com/store
   - www.subdomain2.domain.com redirect to subdomain2.domain.com/store
3. the main domain does not redirect but the domain with www. is rewritten to without the www ie

   - domain.com does not redirect or change
   - www.domain.com rewrites to domain.com
4. all options should work for http and https, ie http remains http and https remains https after any redirection or rewrite

Note: all subdomains points to the same main web folder.

What i have so far

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com/store/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using "rewrite" and "redirect" the right way? *Redirect* means, externally telling the browser to go to a new location, *rewrite* means internally rewrite a URI while apache is processing a URL in the URL-file mapping pipeline (i.e. the browser is completely unaware of any of it)

Comment: @Jon Thanks, i did want the redirect however in thinking it through a little more i change dthe structure of my webpage to reduct the complexity of the redirects and rewrites.